# XSLT, get node with its ancestors

Tags: xslt-2.0

I need to figure out how to extract a node with its ancestors. For example, given a value of "Spine Percutaneous Interventions" and a mapping of

```
  <mdCategoryMapping>
      <mdCategory title="Cerebrovascular" order="20">
         <mdCategory title="Endovascular Surgical Neuroradiology" order="230">
            <mdCategory title="Aneurysms and Subarachnoid Hemorrhage" order="2310" />
            <mdCategory title="Brain Arteriovenous Malformations" order="2320" />
            <mdCategory title="Cranial Dural Arteriovenous Shunts" order="2330" />
            <mdCategory title="Head and Neck Vascular Lesions" order="2340" />
            <mdCategory title="Pediatric Vascular Interventions" order="2350" />
            <mdCategory title="Spine Percutaneous Interventions" order="2360" />
            <mdCategory title="Spine Vascular Interventions" order="2365" />
            <mdCategory title="Stroke" order="2370" />
            <mdCategory title="Trauma" order="2380" />
            <mdCategory title="Tumors" order="2390" />
         </mdCategory>
      </mdCategory>
  </mdCategoryMapping>
```

I need the following result:

```
<mdCategory title="Cerebrovascular" order="20">
    <mdCategory title="Endovascular Surgical Neuroradiology" order="230">
        <mdCategory title="Spine Percutaneous Interventions" order="2360" />
    </mdCategory>
</mdCategory>
```

Of course the following only gives me the lowest level category when $next-cat equals "Spine Percutaneous Interventions".

```
    <xsl:copy-of select="//enes:metaInfo/enes:mdCategoryMapping//enes:mdCategory[@title = $next-cat]" />
```

Result:

```
<mdCategory title="Spine Percutaneous Interventions" order="2360" />
```

Likewise, when $next-cat equals "Cerebrovascular" I get the whole tree with all child nodes.

How do I get the lowest-level node with its ancestors or the top-level node with only selected child nodes?

Comment: Can you please post your complete XSLT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know how to select the element you are interested in or the elements you are interested in then you can select them, select their ancestors and make sure your templates just copy these nodes:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:param name="next-cat" select="'Spine Percutaneous Interventions'"/>

<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:output indent="yes"/>

<xsl:variable name="selected-cat" select="//mdCategory[@title = $next-cat]"/>
<xsl:variable name="subtree" select="$selected-cat/ancestor-or-self::*"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="$subtree[2]"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*">
  <xsl:copy/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*[. intersect $subtree]">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* , node()[. intersect $subtree]"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I could not get the above to work, so I constructed the elements in my XSLT.